# Replace a word in a XSLFTextRun with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am using Apache POI to modify a pptx. I am trying to replace one word in a XSLFTextShape while keeping the formatting of the other words in the XSLFTextShape .

What I tried so far is the following:

```
private static void replaceText(XSLFTextShape textShape, String marker, String newText){
        textShape.setText(textShape.getText().replace(marker, newText));
    }
```

This is replacing the word I want, but the formatting of the other words in the same XSLFTextShape  is changed. For example: If I have a word in the same XSLFTextShape  which is red, the color of this word is changed to black even though I am not changing anything in this word.

Therefore I tried to replace the word in the XSLFTextRun. This is the code I wrote:

```
    private static void replaceText(XSLFTextShape textShape, String marker, String newText){

        List<XSLFTextParagraph> textParagraphList = textShape.getTextParagraphs();
        textParagraphList.forEach(textParagraph -> {
            List<XSLFTextRun> textRunList = textParagraph.getTextRuns();
            textRunList.forEach(textRun -> {
                if(textRun.getRawText().contains(marker)){
                    textRun.setText(textRun.getRawText().replace(marker, newText));
                }
            });
        });
        //String text = textShape.getText();
        //textShape.setText(textShape.getText().replace(marker, newText));
        //String text2 = textShape.getText();
    }
```

I am not getting any error when running this code, but the word is not replaced and I really don't get why. 
If I add the line `textShape.setText(textShape.getText().replace(marker, newText));` it is replaced. But while debugging, I see that `textShape.getText()`gives the same result before and after this line.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably your `marker` is not contained in one text run but split into multiple text runs. Then `if(textRun.getRawText().contains(marker))` will never be true. Check ths using a debugging output. For example `System.out.println(textRun.getRawText());` before `if(textRun.getRawText().contains(marker)){`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for your answer. I already checked that and I see that the condition is true. If I add the commented out (sorry if this is not the correct term) lines, I see that the variables "text" and "text2" have the same value, so therefore the line ```textShape.setText(textShape.getText().replace(marker, newText)); ```should not do anything as the marker is not there anymore. However, if I don't have this line, the word is not replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I made it work somehow with a (not very nice) workaround:
I am saving the text and style per paragraph, delete the text in the shape and then add new paragraphs with the textruns (including style). Here is the code:

```
private static void replaceTextButKeepStyle(XSLFTextShape textShape, final String marker, final String text) {
    List<XSLFTextParagraph> textParagraphList = textShape.getTextParagraphs();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<TextAndStyle>> textAndStylesTable = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < textParagraphList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<TextAndStyle> textAndStylesParagraph = new ArrayList<>();

        XSLFTextParagraph textParagraph = textParagraphList.get(i);

        List<XSLFTextRun> textRunList = textParagraph.getTextRuns();

        for (Iterator it2 = textRunList.iterator(); it2.hasNext(); ) {
            Object object = it2.next();
            XSLFTextRun textRun = (XSLFTextRun) object;

            //get Color:
            PaintStyle.SolidPaint solidPaint = (PaintStyle.SolidPaint) textRun.getFontColor(); 
            int color = solidPaint.getSolidColor().getColor().getRGB();

            //save text & styles:
            TextAndStyle textAndStyle = new TextAndStyle(textRun.getRawText(), textRun.isBold(),
                    color, textRun.getFontSize());

            //replace text if marker:
            if (textAndStyle.getText().contains(marker)) {
                textAndStyle.setText(textAndStyle.getText().replace(marker, text));
            }

            textAndStylesParagraph.add(textAndStyle);
        }
        textAndStylesTable.add(textAndStylesParagraph);
    }

    //delete text and add new text with correct styles:
    textShape.clearText();
    textAndStylesTable.forEach(textAndStyles -> {
        XSLFTextParagraph textParagraph = textShape.addNewTextParagraph();
        textAndStyles.forEach(textAndStyle -> {
            TextRun newTextrun = textParagraph.addNewTextRun();
            newTextrun.setText(textAndStyle.getText());
            newTextrun.setFontColor(new Color(textAndStyle.getColorRgb()));
            newTextrun.setBold(textAndStyle.isBold());
            newTextrun.setFontSize(textAndStyle.getFontsize());
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next example work:

```
private static void replace(XSLFTextParagraph paragraph, String searchValue, String replacement) {
    List<XSLFTextRun> textRuns = paragraph.getTextRuns();
    for (XSLFTextRun textRun : textRuns) {
        if (hasReplaceableItem(textRun.getRawText(), searchValue)) {
            String replacedText = StringUtils.replace(textRun.getRawText(), searchValue, replacement);
            textRun.setText(replacedText);
            break;
        }
    }
}
    
private static boolean hasReplaceableItem(String runText, String searchValue) {
   return StringUtils.contains(runText, searchValue);
}
```

For example I'm used:

- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0
- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9

Pictures before and after:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Savinl, thanks for your answer. But my text still does not get replaced. (Yes, I also updated to the versions you are using). But I did some workaround which I am going to post, so I made it work for me.